System Info program doesn't show disk size
In 24.04.1 GUI program System Info displays disk size 'unkown'. Console program df works normally.



Please edit your question to include the output of df and "System Info" screenshot.

I have edited the question, added screenshots

The problem has been solved in UEFI Bios Update or (less likely) in system update. Now the disk size is shown correctly.

The disk size is still not displaying after sleep mode. Reboot, and it is displaying. I think it was not fixed completely.
